# Can Node.js be run within Tomcat server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

From what I have read so far in this blog http://nowjs.com/  I need to install nodejs in the server machine for it to work. But, I am using a shared server and don't really have any authority to put something into the server machine.

Putting it into the container(tomcat) is however another thing which I mostly do.
Generally speaking, when we say server we mean tomcat or websphere or jboss.

But with nodejs if I am not wrong server means the real machine on which  tomcat etc. runs.

So is there any way I can run the nodejs server inside tomcat server or am I thinking about it the wrong way ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you are thinking of it it the wrong way. The key feature of Nodejs is that it contains, amongst other things, a rather natty embedded HTTP server. Think Jetty. However it *might* be possible now or in the future to run JavaScript in tomcat.

I recommend going to http://nodejs.org/ and watching the video, it will surely clear the matter up for you.

Meanwhile I would recommend getting hosting which includes SSH access, and preferably root access. Root access will make installing node a whole load easier and allow you to run it on a commonly used port (avoid running node as root, use port mapping) . But you don't need a seperate web server to get started, you can install Node.js on windows, mac and linux.

Comment: so it will be like moving altogether from tomcat isn't it ? but where thenwill i run my java servlet code ? will nodejs run that too ?

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but I would advise having them run on different server instances if you want to run HTTP services in each.

Comment: or run node on a different port.