# Is there a way to run a Node.js application within a Tomcat server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tomcat, webserver

I have a REST Web Service running within Tomcat and I do not want to run the Node.js application manually. Can I somehow run my Node application using Tomcat?

Comment: "I do not want to run the Node.js application manually" You should expand on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Node.js be run within Tomcat server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618306/can-node-js-be-run-within-tomcat-server)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run Nodejs server inside tomcat.

I would suggest to ge to http://nodejs.org/ and read some docs and refer some videos.

I have used [openshift](https://www.openshift.com)  to host my node js application

please refer [this](https://seroter.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/where-the-heck-do-i-host-my-node-js-app/) link to know more about where to host nodejs application