# How to integrate a React webapp inside a spring boot Application with jar packaging

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, webpack, maven-3

We have a react webapp and a spring boot application(built with maven) in development.
The React app(on npm) and boot app are running separately but time has come to now integrate them and put it into QA/staging.
We are using webpack for bundling the react application.
The boot app is a single module with REST API(consumed by the react front-end) with hibernate for database persistence.

Questions

1. What should be the directory structure for both react and boot app? We want to deploy the whole app(front-end and back-end) as a .jar (spring boot uberjar)
2. What is the react app development workflow ? A workflow without having to run maven and run java -jar every time a small css, html or .js change is made.

I found resources on web where both the react and the boot applications were on separate repos/directories without any integration, which is not optimal; I am yet to find a resource where both webapp resources and boot resources are in the same directory tree  which also accounts for development lifecycle and production lifecycle.

Bonus : The react developers know only html/js/css. Is it possible that they have only the react app resources in their vscode/webstorm project ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest creating multimodule maven project, where one module will be spring-boot app and second one react app. To make it into uber jar, pack react app into [webjar](https://www.webjars.org/) build by maven.
Building can be done also by maven with proper plugin.

So:

1. Create normal react app (build by npm and so on) in sub directory of you project
2. Add to this app pom.xml which will [compile javascript on maven compile](https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/including-react-in-your-spring-boot-maven-build-ae3b8f8826e) and [pack it into proper webjar structure](https://www.webjars.org/contributing)
3. In spring-boot module add react one as normal maven dependency. [Check out this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-webjars)

This will allow you to have everything as one uber jar app. On the other hand, front-end people can work with react module as with any other react application.

Comment: Question is is this the best practice? To have both in one jar? Or is it better to deploy react and spring boot separately on the machine?

Comment: It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 30):

You can run React and SpringBoot on the same port and Package them as a single artifact !!
Please follow the steps that I have explained here, that should get you up and running.
To answer your questions-

1. **The directory structure has been show below. Both will be under the same root directory.**
2. **Regarding react app development workflow- you can just develop it the way you develop a front-end react project, with hot reloads(save the file and the changes will reflect automatically) and meaningful error messages. You will have to use proxying to communicate.**

> Here is the [Github](https://github.com/arpan-banerjee7/demo-spring-react-maven-plugin) link of the demo project that I am going to
> explain here

Spring Boot can serve static content from `src/main/resources/static` folder. We will exploit the above mentioned feature of Spring Boot to serve the single page of the react project. We will serve a html page from the static folder in the target directory, not in the source directory.

The **Project structure**-

[image]

First, create a spring boot project with https://start.spring.io. Add the Web dependency. Set the groupId and artifactId to whatever you want. Generate the project and unzip it into your project directory.

Or, if you are using Spring Tools Suite you can simply click
`File->New->Spring Starter Project` and mention the required details to create a spring boot project.

The `frontend` folder inside `src/main` should have your react application build using  [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html).

**So, there are two steps-**

1. create a production build of the frontend.
2. copy the production build into ${target/classes/}.

**We we will use two maven plugins and [Thymleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) for that.**

1. [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) for step 1.
2. [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) for step 2.

**For [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) at Step 1--** If you closely look at the `pom.xml` there I have mentioned the `src` directroy from where [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) will take the files, create the production build and place the contents inside the output directory mentioned(inside `src/main/frontend/build`).

```
 <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
 <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
```

**For [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) at step 2--** It will take the production build that was just created by [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) and place it inside your root directory then `target/classes/static`.

**Then we will use [Thymleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/)** to serve the static content from the `target/classes/static` using a rest endpoint in the controller. Or else you have to type in the name of the `html file`, like `http://localhost:8080/index.html`

Your **pom.xml** should look like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springreact</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Run React Frontend and SpringBoot Backend on the same port.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <frontend-src-dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontend-src-dir>
        <node.version>v14.15.4</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.16.0</yarn.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.7.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn-install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>build-frontend</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>position-react-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${frontend-src-dir}/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the **Controller** code.

```
package com.springreact.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("index");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

If you follow the above mentioned steps , you should see your React App being spun up on `http://localhost:8080/`.

[image]

*For further details you can checkout the  blog that I have written on it. Here are the links  of the blog on two different platforms-*

Dev Community- https://dev.to/arpan_banerjee7/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-14pa

Medium- https://medium.com/codex/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-a790c9e10ac1

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  Have been trying to figure this out for day.  I'm an experienced Java developer but new to Javascript frameworks.  It was so hard to find clear instructions on how to do this

Comment: Thanks Arpan! I'm starting the process of separating the frontend from a Spring Boot application to a webpack built frontend, most likely React, and at the moment I can't split them up in maven modules with two separate jar files. Your solution fits my project perfectly and it's very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question on whether it is best practice to create an uber jar or to package the app in a single jar. It depends on certain things. Like for ex. If you have oauth2 implemented in your app and would like to access the rest end points without having to implement the logic of access token and such. You could put it in a single jar. else you'd have to create a header with the access token in the header.