# hosting nodejs code in Apache Tomcat server

Tags: node.js, tomcat

Is it possible to host a node.js application on Apache tomcat server and then expose an https url from it? I would like to access the https url from other machines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Node.js be run within Tomcat server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618306/can-node-js-be-run-within-tomcat-server)