# Is it possible to enable database connection using NodeJS within react app and deploy bundled file in server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Here is my situation

I have a React app which uses Webpack to bundle all modules. Now I want to get data from database and show it in the App.

I understand we can develop node/Java backend service which will run on different port and access it from React app either using fetch/ajax but I don’t want backend service to run on different port.

I want to enable database connection within React app and get data from DB in the component. So, can I establish a database connection to get data from database within React app and bundle this node code in Webpack bundle.js? Will I be able to get data from database when this bundled file deployed in server? Eg. tomcat

Please suggest possible solution

Answer (score 1):

No, you wont, that's all because react is used in the front end.

However, you should check out [React Server Side Rendering (SSR)](https://alligator.io/react/server-side-rendering/). That will definitely accomplish your task

Comment: [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) is a nice framework for SSR!

Comment: Ok. If I have server side react in my node service. Can that be deployed in tomcat?

Comment: The problem which I am facing right now is I have my backend service in node js and front end in ReactJS and both has to be deployed only in tomcat server.

Comment: @tico next.js is a Cisco framework for topology view right? Can you please let me know how that will help in my case.

Comment: If you want your application to follow microservice architecture, I would suggest you to have a separate backend service (node/java) and expose an API to fetch the data from DB.

Comment: @vasuki I do not want micro service I have React app that should fetch data from dB using Node.js and that should be deployed in Tomcat server. Is there a way to do this? Because if I create node js microservice I cant deploy that in tomcat server. So, but I want my backend to be written only in node js and that should be deployed in tomcat server along with React app. I have only tomcat server

Comment: @HemadriDasari No, maybe you're confusing it. Please check the link in the original post -- Straight from the GitHub repo: **Next.js is a minimalistic framework for server-rendered React applications.**

Comment: @HemadriDasari About installing a NodeJS app in Tomcat, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618306/can-node-js-be-run-within-tomcat-server it will guide you even better